# Antonym for contra?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the bolded phrase [below](https://oll.libertyfund.org/pages/millar-and-the-distinction-of-ranks), is there an obviously Latin-derived word we can use to replace "following"? (Perhaps *pro*?)

> But Millar presumed, **following Hume and *contra* Montesquieu**, that mores or “moral causes,” as opposed to physical causes such as climate, are responsible for characteristic differences in human population.

Edit: I take *contra* to mean *against* and *following* to mean *for*. I'm wondering if there's a Latin word that serves as the standard antonym for *contra* and which could replace *following*.

Comment: Can you explain what you want it to mean?

Comment: Sometimes we see arguments divided in to *pro* and *contra*.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could replace "following" with a more classic antonym of contra, but I'm not sure why you would want to. The result would be much less idiomatic. I believe your interpretation of "following" to mean "pro" is a bit premature. The usage here most resembles this definition from M-W:

**follow**
verb- to walk or proceed along (as a road or course)

In this way, to "follow" an argument simply means to trace it's reasoning, taking it at face value. You can be completely opposed to an idea, and still use "following" where "pro" would not make sense. For example: "Following your reasoning, since the sun will go supernova in 20 billion years, there is absolutely no point in recycling this aluminum can! What a rubbish argument!"

Answer (score 1):

According to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/contrahttps://), the antonym of *contra* is **pro**, which, again, according to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pro) means "on the affirmative side : in affirmation." I agree with @lumbrjak though that it's not clear why you would want to replace *following* with *pro*: "*following Hume*" doesn't mean the same thing as "*pro* Hume". Also, **contra**, when opposed to **following**, means something like *not following*, *against the thinking of*.

If you want to oppose a Latin word to *contra* and stick with **following**, you could use **secundum**? From Wiktinary:

> [**secundum**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secundum): according to

Your example:

> But Millar presumed, **secundum** Hume and contra Montesquieu, that mores or “moral causes,” as opposed to physical causes such as climate, are responsible for characteristic differences in human population.

Another possibility is **as per**. From Lexico:

> **[as per](https://www.lexico.com/definition/as_per)**: In accordance with.

Your example:

> But Millar presumed, **as per** Hume and contra Montesquieu, that mores or “moral causes,” as opposed to physical causes such as climate, are responsible for characteristic differences in human population.

**As per** is not Latin, but it sounds like it is. :-)